# How to avoid Nested synchronization and the resulting deadlock

Tags: java, concurrency, locks

I need to lock two objects in a functionality and the current code looke like this;

```
Object obj1  = ...//get from somewhere
Object obj2 = ...//get from somewhere

synchronized(obj1){
  ...//blah
  synchronized(obj2){
     ...//blah
  }
}
```

As you can see this is a plain and straight recipe for deadlocks if another thread runs this piece of code with obj1 and two reversed.
Is there a way to avoid this situation using concurrency-utils locks?

I was contemplating maintaining a map of objects and their locks and verifying if they were available to take, but can't seem to come up with a clean way which will predict the lock order.

Comment: I just fixed your formatting, and now you ruined it again. Look at the preview! You see that it's all messed up. You need to select the code and press CTRL+K.

Comment: My IE6 (the only one allowed at workplace :( ) is bad at stackoverflow's edit toolbar. Sorry about that. Fixed the formatting now.

Comment: if the two objects need to work together then maybe that the functionality you're performing inside your synchronized blocks could be moved to one of these two objects/class (which is just good OO design btw).  As a side benefit, this would greatly help synchronization issues.

Answer (score 7):

Although you preserve locking order, if obj1 is switched with obj2 you'll run into deadlock.

You must look for another solution to avoid this cases: lock ordering + optional tie breaking lock

```
int fromHash = System.identityHashCode(obj1);
int toHash = System.identityHashCode(obj2);

if (fromHash < toHash) {
    synchronized (obj1) {
        synchronized (obj2) {
               ........
        }
    }
} else if (fromHash > toHash) {
    synchronized (obj2) {
        synchronized (obj1) {
            ........
        }
    }
} else {
    synchronized (TIE_LOCK) {
        synchronized (fromAcct) {
            synchronized (toAcct) {
               ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Another option is using Lock.tryLock. Check 13.1.2 from Java Concurrency in Practice

Comment: You might want to add to the first if `obj1 == obj2 || ` (or specially handle and prohibit if it doesn't make sense).

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you are doing you may be able to take what you want from the first locked object and use that information to process the second locked object. e.g.

instead of

```
synchronized(list1) {
  for(String s : list1) {
     synchronized(list2) {
       // do something with both lists.
     }
  }
}
```

do this

```
List<String> listCopy;
synchronized(list1) {
  listCopy = new ArrayList<String>(list1);
}

synchornized(list2) {
   // do something with liastCopy and list2
}
```

You can see you only have lock at a time so you won't get a deadlock.

Answer (score 3):

You need to consistently lock in the order of obj1 and then obj2. If you never violate this order, you won't have deadlocks.

Comment: Is there any reference implementation you can point to? I tried lock1. lock() and a nested lock2.lock() where lock1 and lock2 are locks specific to obj1, obj2. But that doesn't seem to solve it any more than nested synchronized.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of reference you need. It's really just the rule that you may never lock obj2 and then obj1 - if you intend to lock them both, you need to lock obj1 and then obj2. As long as you do that, you're fine. If not, please show an example of where it doesn't work.

Comment: Lets say I get obj1 and obj2 from cache based on user supplied keys. In this case there's no way to say specific obj1 will be locked before obj2 right? It would result in a deadlock like @Ovidiu said if two users provide opposite keys at the same time.

Comment: @VarunGarde Lock-ordering is one common approach. Arguably a better approach is not to nest locks. In that particular case, if there keys do  not share locks, then you have the choice of ordering based on the locked object or the key.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what you have is the dining philospher's problem.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem

Ovidiu Lupas's answer is similar to Dijkstra's Resource Heirarchy solution, but there are 3 more solutions, explained on the wiki page

This is what the arbitrator solution looks like. If all of the objects which you're operating from inherit from the same type, you could use static class variables to implement the arbitrators on the class of objects.

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;

public void init()
{
  Lock arbitrator = new Lock();
}

public void meth1()
{
  arbitrator.lock();
  synchronized (obj1) {
    synchronized (obj2) {
      arbitrator.unlock();
      // Do Stuff
    }
  }
}

public void meth2()
{
  arbitrator.lock();
  synchronized (obj2) {
    synchronized (obj1) {
      arbitrator.unlock();
      // Do Stuff
    }
  }
}
```

The Chandy/Misra solution requires a lot of message passing so I'm not going to implement it, but wikipedia has a pretty good explaination

Comment: "meth1" nice 

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it in other way I suppose.

```
class Obj implements Comparable<Obj> {
    // basically your original class + compare(Obj other) implementation
}

class ObjLock implements Lock, Comparable<ObjLock> {

    private final Lock lock;
    private final Obj obj; // your original object

    ObjLock(Obj obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
        this.lock = new ReentrantLock();
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(ObjLock other) {
         return this.obj.compare(other.obj); // ObjLock comparison based on Obj comparison
    }

    // + reimplement Lock methods with this.lock invocations

}
```

Then do

```
class ObjLocksGroup {

    private final List<ObjLock> objLocks;

    ObjLocksGroup(ObjLock... objLocks) {
        this.objLocks = stream(objLocks)
                .sorted() // due to ObjLock implements Comparable and sorting you are sure that order of ObjLock... will always be the same
                .collect(toList));
    }

    void lock() {
        this.objLocks.forEach(ObjLock::lock);
    }

    void unlock() {
        this.objLocks.forEach(ObjLock::unlock);
    }
}
```

And use it as you want:

```
ObjLocksGroup locks = new ObjLocksGroup(obj1, obj2) // the same as obj2, obj1, order does not matter anymore.
locks.lock();
locks.unlock();
```