# Java : Does wait() release lock from synchronized block

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking, wait

I was under the impression that wait() releases all locks but I found this post which says

"Invoking wait inside a synchronized method is a simple way to acquire the intrinsic lock"

Please clarify I'm a bit confused.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Comment: I think you are wrong wait does release the lock and suspend execution. Its also written on the same link on the very next line.

Comment: Yup, you are right, "Some time after the second thread has released the lock, the first thread reacquires the lock and resumes by returning from the invocation of wait.". But what is most important is "wait tells current thread that it should stop until some other thread calls notify(or notifyAll) on same object"

Comment: The `wait` function doesn't release "all locks", but it does release the lock associated with the object on which `wait` is invoked.

Answer (score 182):

"Invoking wait inside a synchronized method is a simple way to acquire the intrinsic lock"

**This sentence is false, it is an error in documentation.**

Thread acquires the intrinsic lock when it **enters** a synchronized method.
Thread inside the synchronized method is set as the owner of the lock and is in **RUNNABLE** state.
Any thread that attempts to enter the locked method becomes **BLOCKED**.

When thread calls wait it releases the current object lock (it keeps all locks from other objects) and than goes to **WAITING** state.

When some other thread calls notify or notifyAll on that same object the first thread changes state from WAITING to BLOCKED,
Notified thread does NOT automatically reacquire the lock or become RUNNABLE, in fact it must fight for the lock with all other blocked threads.

WAITING and BLOCKED states both prevent thread from running, but they are very different.

WAITING threads must be explicitly transformed to BLOCKED threads by a notify from some other thread.

WAITING never goes directly to RUNNABLE.

When RUNNABLE thread releases the lock (by leaving monitor or by waiting) one of BLOCKED threads automatically takes its place.

So to summarize, thread acquires the lock when it enters synchronized method or when it reenters the synchronized method **after** the wait.

```
public synchronized guardedJoy() {
    // must get lock before entering here
    while(!joy) {
        try {
            wait(); // releases lock here
            // must regain the lock to reentering here
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
    System.out.println("Joy and efficiency have been achieved!");
}
```

Comment: what if I have two nested synchronized blocks and invoke wait()? is it supported?

Comment: @serine, yeah it is, and it can easily cause a deadlock. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10365261/1001883) answer for more explicit information.

Comment: If InterruptedException was thrown does the current thread have to acquire object lock to come into a catch block?

Comment: Assume there is only one thread and waited on some time in millis; now Is it possible a thread can directly from waiting state to go to runnable state? since no other thread takes lock here since only single threaded? I asked this because you have told "WAITING never goes directly to RUNNABLE."

Comment: @cohadar : should it be  "in fact it must fight for the lock with all other WAITING threads"

Comment: Just for sake of knowledge - A thread can have simultaneous locks on multiple object. One example being nested synchronized blocks. Or synchronized method containing synchronized block(s).

Answer (score 24):

I've prepared a small test class (some very dirty code, sorry) to demonstrate that wait actually releases the lock.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        testCuncurrency();
    }

    private static void testCuncurrency() throws InterruptedException {
        Object lock = new Object();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new WaitTester(lock));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new WaitTester(lock));
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        Thread.sleep(15 * 1000);
        synchronized (lock) {
            System.out.println("Time: " + new Date().toString()+ ";" + "Notifying all");
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    private static class WaitTester implements Runnable {
        private Object lock;
        public WaitTester(Object lock) {
            this.lock = lock;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    System.out.println(getTimeAndThreadName() + ":only one thread can be in synchronized block");
                    Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);

                    System.out.println(getTimeAndThreadName() + ":thread goes into waiting state and releases the lock");
                    lock.wait();

                    System.out.println(getTimeAndThreadName() + ":thread is awake and have reacquired the lock");

                    System.out.println(getTimeAndThreadName() + ":syncronized block have finished");
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    private static String getTimeAndThreadName() {
        return "Time: " + new Date().toString() + ";" + Thread.currentThread().getName();
    }
}
```

Running this class on my machine returns next result:

```
Time: Tue Mar 29 09:16:37 EEST 2016;Thread-0:only one thread can be in synchronized block
Time: Tue Mar 29 09:16:42 EEST 2016;Thread-0:thread goes into waiting state and releases the lock
Time: Tue Mar 29 09:16:42 EEST 2016;Thread-1:only one thread can be in synchronized block
Time: Tue Mar 29 09:16:47 EEST 2016;Thread-1:thread goes into waiting state and releases the lock
Time: Tue Mar 29 09:16:52 EEST 2016;Notifying all
Time: Tue Mar 29 09:16:52 EEST 2016;Thread-1:thread is awake and have reacquired the lock
Time: Tue Mar 29 09:16:57 EEST 2016;Thread-1:syncronized block have finished
Time: Tue Mar 29 09:16:57 EEST 2016;Thread-0:thread is awake and have reacquired the lock
Time: Tue Mar 29 09:17:02 EEST 2016;Thread-0:syncronized block have finished
```

Comment: Very nice example buddy!

Answer (score 9):

> `wait` :: is part of `java.lang.Object` class, so we can call this method only on the object. calling this needs monitor(lock) on that object, else
>   `IllegalMonitorStateException` will be thrown, e.g)
>   Thread.currentThread().wait() will throw this exception at below code.
>
> ```
>    Example1
>    public void doSomething() {                                          Line 1
>         synchronized(lockObject) { //lock acquired                      Line 2
>             lockObject.wait();     // NOT Thread.currentThread().wait() Line 3
>         }
>     }
> ```
>
> Now calling wait at Line 3 will release the lock acquired at Line 2. So any other thread entered into Line 1 and waiting to acquire lock on `lockObject` will acquire this lock and proceeds.
>
> Now let us consider this `Example2`; here only `lockObject2` lock is released, and still current thread holds `lockObject1` lock. This will leads to deadlock; So user should be more careful on this case.
>
> ```
>    Example2 
>         public void doSomething() {                                     Line 1
>              synchronized(lockObject1) { //lock1 acquired               Line 2
>                  synchronized(lockObject2) { //lock2 acquired           Line 3
>                      lockObject2.wait();                                Line 4
>                  }
>              }
>         }
> ```
>
> If this wait is replaced with `sleep, yield, or join` they dont have
>   cabaility to release the lock. Only wait can release lock that it holds.
>
> Just cautious on `t1.sleep()/t1.yield()` where are static api's and always
>   action will be performed on the `currentThread` not on thread `t1`.
>
> Then let us understand what is the difference between `suspend` and these api's `sleep, yield, join`; because `suspend` is deprecated to avoid situation of the thread is holding the lock which will leads to deadlock when it is in suspended (not running state) for undefined time. This is the same behavior for other apis as well.
>
> The answer is suspend/resume will be performed on other threads, like `t1.suspend()` where as these api's are suspending the
>   `Thread.currentThread()`.
>       Hence user has caution note on taking care of not holding any locks before calling these api's to avoid deadlock. This is not the
>   case when calling `suspend`. The callee thread don't know about the caller thread (lock)
>   state on which it is going to perform suspend, hence deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

I think this statement should be seen within its full context.

> When a thread invokes d.wait, it must own the intrinsic lock for d —
>   otherwise an error is thrown. Invoking wait inside a synchronized
>   method is a simple way to acquire the intrinsic lock.

I understand that they should simplify this to be like:

> Invocation of `synchronized` methods acquires lock on
>   object, we can simply put a `wait()` invocation inside a `synchronized` method.