# When a lock is released?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I found three cases when a lock on a resource is released:

```
1) wait() method;
2) get an exception;
3) thread complete its execution
```

Are there other cases?

Comment: Uhm, *who* release the lock then? From what source were those cases determined? And what is *really* meant by 'lock is released'? For instance `synchronized (x) { /* lock will not be released until this block exits */ }` runs counter to the stated cases.

Comment: For example, if I have something  like this:
`synchronized void method() {
while(condition)
wait()
......
doAction;
notifyAll();
}`
If the while condition is right my thread releases its lock. I want to know, in general, if there are other cases.

Comment: Might be useful reading - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249835/java-does-wait-release-lock-from-synchronized-block