# Suspend consumer in producer/consumer pattern

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer, blockingqueue

I have producer and consumer connected with `BlockingQueue`.

Consumer wait records from queue and process it:

```
Record r = mQueue.take();
process(r);
```

I need pause this process for a while from other thread. How to implement it?

Now I think implement it such, but it's looks like bad solution:

```
private Object mLock = new Object();
private boolean mLocked = false;

public void lock() {
    mLocked = true;
}

public void unlock() {
    mLocked = false;
    mLock.notify();

}

public void run() {
    ....
            Record r = mQueue.take();
            if (mLocked) {
                mLock.wait();
            }
            process(r);
}
```

Comment: Do you mind providing a bit more context on your specific need? The reason I ask, is that if I really need to pause someone in the chain, I would much rather pause the producer rather than the consumer.  It basically achieves a similar effect without having the queue grow to capacity while the pause is in effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your solution is simple and elegant, and think you should keep it with some modifications. The modifications I propose are [synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html).

Without it, thread interference and memory consistancy errors can (and very often does) occur. On top of that, you can't `wait` or `notify` on a lock you don't own (and you own it if you have it inside a `synchronized` block..). The fix is easy, just add a `mLock` synchronize block where you wait/notify on it. Also, as you're changing `mLocked` from a different thread you will want to mark it [volatile](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml).

```
private Object mLock = new Object();
private volatile boolean mLocked = false;

public void lock() {
    mLocked = true;
}

public void unlock() {
    synchronized(mlock) {
        mLocked = false;
        mLock.notify();
    }

}

public void run() {
    ....
            Record r = mQueue.take();
            synchronized(mLock) {
                while (mLocked) {
                    mLock.wait();
                }
            }
            process(r);
}
```

Comment: I wrote the same code. But then I thought that if you go in sync block with the wait, then I don't to go in sync block with notify. But I was wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249835/java-does-wait-release-lock-from-synchronized-block

Comment: May be will be better replace if (mLocked) on while(mLocked). http://stackoverflow.com/a/2779565/1173794

Answer (score 2):

You can use `java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition` [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) to pause for a while based on same condition.

This is approach looks clean to me and **ReentrantLock mechanism has better throughput than synchronized**. Read below excerpt from [IBM article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp10264/)

> As a bonus, the implementation of ReentrantLock is far more scalable
>   under contention than the current implementation of synchronized. (It
>   is likely that there will be improvements to the contended performance
>   of synchronized in a future version of the JVM.) **This means that when
>   many threads are all contending for the same lock, the total
>   throughput is generally going to be better with ReentrantLock than
>   with synchronized.**

**BlockingQueue are best known for solution of producer-consumer problem, and it also uses `Condition` for waiting.**

See below example taken from Java doc's [Condition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html), which is a sample implementation of producer - consumer pattern.

```
class BoundedBuffer {
   final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
   final Condition notFull  = lock.newCondition(); 
   final Condition notEmpty = lock.newCondition(); 

   final Object[] items = new Object[100];
   int putptr, takeptr, count;

   public void put(Object x) throws InterruptedException {
     lock.lock();
     try {
       while (count == items.length)
         notFull.await();
       items[putptr] = x;
       if (++putptr == items.length) putptr = 0;
       ++count;
       notEmpty.signal();
     } finally {
       lock.unlock();
     }
   }

   public Object take() throws InterruptedException {
     lock.lock();
     try {
       while (count == 0)
         notEmpty.await();
       Object x = items[takeptr];
       if (++takeptr == items.length) takeptr = 0;
       --count;
       notFull.signal();
       return x;
     } finally {
       lock.unlock();
     }
   }
 }
```

---

Further reading:

- https://javabeanz.wordpress.com/2007/07/12/using-reentrant-locks-for-thread-synchronization/

Comment: Mr. down Downvoter, can you take the pain to explain your down vote please?

Comment: Man I hate downvotes when the person actually takes some time to provide an insightful explanation. If this solution doesn't work for you, fine. But it doesn't deserve a downvote. +1 for me even if I find the first one simpler, the second offers insight on threads and concurrency.

Comment: not my downvote, but giving a performance judgment based on an article 10+ years old seems iffy.

Comment: @PatB Thanks pal for the stand and support.

Comment: @NathanHughes I would accept your comment, I tried to get some latest reference but couldn't find any in my quick search. But I think this will hold true because this is the same mechanism which is used in BlockingQueue implementations like `ArrayBlockingQueue`, `LinkedBlockingQueue`

Comment: understood, just trying to think like the downvoter here. might help to add something like this to the answer?

Comment: @NathanHughes Based on your comment, I have added a note for blocking queues to give OP confidence of something very latest.

Comment: I don't downvote this answer. But I do not understand how to apply ReentrantLock to my question. More precisely, I tried to do it, but ran into problems. As I understand it, I do not need to use conditions. I need to use the lock / unlock only. But why thread hang in the method unlock?

Comment: What problems you ran into? You don't have any condition or relation between consumers and producers like the one in example? "*But why thread hang in the method unlock?*" I haven't got it, you mean in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new class that extends an implementation of `BlockingQueue`. Add two new methods `pause()` and `unpause()`. Where needed, consider the `paused` flag and use the other `blockingQueue2` to wait (in my example only in the `take()` method, and not in `put()`):

```
public class BlockingQueueWithPause<E> extends LinkedBlockingQueue<E> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 184661285402L;

    private Object lock1 = new Object();//used in pause() and in take()
    private Object lock2 = new Object();//used in pause() and unpause()

    //@GuardedBy("lock")
    private volatile boolean paused;

    private LinkedBlockingQueue<Object> blockingQueue2 = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Object>();

    public void pause() {
        if (!paused) {
            synchronized (lock1) {
            synchronized (lock2) {
                if (!paused) {
                    paused = true;
                    blockingQueue2.removeAll();//make sure it is empty, e.g after successive calls to pause() and unpause() without any consumers it will remain unempty
                }
            }
            }
        }
    }

    public void unpause() throws InterruptedException {
        if (paused) {
            synchronized (lock2) {
                paused = false;
                blockingQueue2.put(new Object());//release waiting thread, if there is one
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public E take() throws InterruptedException {
        E result = super.take();

        if (paused) {
            synchronized (lock1) {//this guarantees that a single thread will be in the synchronized block, all other threads will be waiting
                if (paused) {
                    blockingQueue2.take();
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    //TODO override similarly the poll() method.
}
```