# Guarding state with two locks

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

As [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31564193/suspend-consumer-in-producer-consumer-pattern/31565515#31565515) to the [question about pausing a BlockingQueue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31564193/suspend-consumer-in-producer-consumer-pattern/), I came with the idea of using an existing blocking structure `blockingQueue2` and guarding the state with two different locks.

```
public class BlockingQueueWithPause<E> extends LinkedBlockingQueue<E> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 184661285402L;

    private Object lock1 = new Object();//used in pause() and in take()
    private Object lock2 = new Object();//used in pause() and unpause()

    //@GuardedBy("lock1")
    private volatile boolean paused;

    private LinkedBlockingQueue<Object> blockingQueue2 = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Object>();

    public void pause() {
        if (!paused) {
            synchronized (lock1) {
            synchronized (lock2) {
                if (!paused) {
                    paused = true;
                    blockingQueue2.removeAll();//make sure it is empty, e.g after successive calls to pause() and unpause() without any consumers it will remain unempty
                }
            }
            }
        }
    }

    public void unpause() throws InterruptedException {
        if (paused) {
            synchronized (lock2) {
                paused = false;
                blockingQueue2.put(new Object());//will release waiting thread, if there is one
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public E take() throws InterruptedException {
        E result = super.take();

        if (paused) {
            synchronized (lock1) {//this guarantees that a single thread will be in the synchronized block, all other threads will be waiting
                if (paused) {
                    blockingQueue2.take();
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    //TODO override similarly the poll() method.
}
```

I need two different locks, otherwise the `unpause()` could wait for the `lock1` held already in `take()` by a consumer thread.

My questions:

1. Could this come to a deadlock?
2. Does it work at all?
3. How often did you see such code, as I myself don't find it readable?
4. How should I annotate the `paused` flag: with `@GuardedBy("lock1, locks2")`?

PS: Any improvements are welcome (beside that I could have used a binary semaphore instead of `blockingQueue2`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer your questions one by one

> Could this come to a deadlock?

No you will not result in a deadlock.  If you obtained `lock1` and `lock2` in different orders than that could result in a deadlock.  Since you obtain them in the same order when holding both you should be fine.

> Does it work at all?

It appears to. All happens-before ordering seems to be satisfied.

> How often did you see such code, as I myself don't find it readable?

I've never seen this sort of implementation before. I agree it isn't very elegant.

---

I am going to pose an alternative solution which uses a [Phaser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html).  One can argue this isn't any more elegant, just an alternate approach.  I have reviewed it for some time and I think it is sufficient.  Granted I've never seen this approach either, but was fun to think up.

```
public static class BlockingQueueWithPause<E> extends LinkedBlockingQueue<E> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 184661285402L;

    private final Phaser phaser = new Phaser(1);
    private volatile int phase = phaser.getPhase();

    public BlockingQueueWithPause() {
        // base case, all phase 0 await's will succeed through.
        phaser.arrive();
    }

    public void pause() {
        phase = phaser.getPhase();
    }

    public void unpause() throws InterruptedException {
        phaser.arrive();
    }

    @Override
    public E take() throws InterruptedException {
        phaser.awaitAdvance(phase);

        E result = super.take();

        return result;
    }
}
```

I guess I should explain this solution.  The Phaser is like if the [CylicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) and [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) had a child.  It allows re-using the barrier while not waiting for the barrier to trip.

In the base case, the shared `phase` will be 0. Since `arrive` is called in the constructor the `phaser`'s internal phase is 1.  So, if `take` is invoked without a `pause` ever being called `awaitAdvance` will be called on 0.  Since the internal phase is 1 the phaser fast-path's out and is a simple volatile load (the 0 phase already occurred so we no longer have to wait for advance).

If `pause` is invoked, the shared `phase` variable will be updated to the phaser's internal phase which is now 1.  So a `take` will `awaitTermination` on 1 causing it to suspend.

The `unpause` arrive will cause all threads `awaitAdvance`ing to release and increment the phaser's internal phase to 2.  Again, subsequent take's will fast-path out without a corresponding pause.

Comment: Nice answer: I find your solution with the `Phaser` more elegant, as it is more concise and has no composite atomic operations.

Comment: @AndreiI Thanks, hope it can work.  This was a fun one for me, took me some time to really iron it out :)