# Is it deadlockable?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm coding a web-service using Java. Also I've got a resource, so access to this resource should be synchronized. I'm using 2 different locks: `saltLock` and `waitLock`. Is this code seems deadlockable?

```
    @WebMethod(operationName = "getSalt")
    public String getSalt() {
    synchronized(waitLock)
    {
      //wait until ip is already in use
      //could wait a lot
      synchronized(saltLock)
      {
         //modify resource
      }
    }
   } 

@WebMethod(operationName = "doSmt")
public String doSmt()
{
   //some code...
  synchronized(saltLock)
  {
     //modify resource
  } 
}
```

**BONUS QUESTIONS:**

1) Is it ok to use inner `synchronized`?

2) Does `synchronized(waitLock)` block its inner `synchronized(saltLock)`?

Comment: Check this link [Nested synchronization blocks][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365132/java-nested-synchronization-blocks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. yes
2. no

this code is ok, no deadlock problem.

this code may deadlock:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "getSalt")
public String getSalt() {
synchronized(waitLock)
{
  //wait until ip is already in use
  //could wait a lot
  synchronized(saltLock)
  {
     //modify resource
  }
}


@WebMethod(operationName = "doSmt")
public String doSmt()
{
   //some code...
  synchronized(saltLock)
  {
     //modify resource
     synchronized(waitLock) {
      // some code
     }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If that's the only locking you do on `saltLock` and `waitLock`, and `doSmt()` can't call `getSalt()`, it's safe.

Deadlocks occur when different threads attempt to acquire multiple locks in different orders. Here, the second thread only acquires only one lock, so it's thread safe.

Comment: Also I've got few methods like `doSmth()`. They do the same thing, only `//some code...`'s are different. All of them are having one `synchronized(saltLock)` in the end. Is it ok?

Comment: @Tony Yes, they are okay.