# How can JAVA give two lock to the same code segment?

Tags: java, locking, synchronized

I have two locks -- lock1 and lock2 in my code, and I want to give one code segment these two lock as follows:

```
synchronized(lock1 || lock2) {
    // code
}
```

This means that if lock1 or lock2 is busy, this code segment will wait until both locks free. How can I do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can nest them:

```
synchronized (lock1) {
    synchronized (lock2) {
        //code
    }
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10365261/1039555) for the possible risks associated with nested locking.

Comment: You might want to add that this carries a tremendous risk of deadlock, that order of locking is extremely important, and that the question seems as if it might be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) type question